# How to display the GUI elements from derived XAML too?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, inheritance, xamarin.forms

I succeeded inheriting from class ContentPage, the derived class is called SubContentPage.
It contains some template elements (button and title label).
I have two classes FilterPage and SettingsPage which inherit from SubContentPage. When I display one of these derived pages, I can only see the GUI contents of the SubContentPage although when FilterPage and SettingsPage inherited from ContentPage before, it worked. So my GUI code is not wrong.

My idea was that SubContentPage and the derived classes don't use the same Content where the graphical controls appear. So the derived GUI elements are ignored.
I tried to use for the classes SubContentPage and FilterPage the same StackLayout name. But this won't work.

SubContentPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="solna_app.GUI.Pages.SubContentPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image x:Name="BackIcon" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                    Grid.Row="0" />
                <Label x:Name="TitleLabel" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold"
                    TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="0" />
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

FilterPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<d:SubContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="clr-namespace:solna_app.GUI.Pages;assembly=solna_app"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="solna_app.GUI.Pages.FilterPage">
    <d:SubContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label  x:Name="SearchLabel" Text="Search keyword" 
                TextColor="Black" FontSize="Large" Margin="10,10,0,0" />
            <Editor x:Name="SearchEditor" Placeholder="Type a keyword"
                PlaceholderColor="Gray" Margin="10,10,10,0"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </d:SubContentPage.Content>
</d:SubContentPage>
```

I expect that the UI controls of SubContentPage AND the UI controls of the derived class are displayed.

Comment: If you replace the Content that the base class had, you’ll get the content you replaced it with. There’s only one Content property. It has only one value. Giving controls the same name won’t affect anything. Subclassing isn’t the way to do this in WPF. You want to do it by composition: A control’s template creates its own controls, and embeds its Content via a ContentPresenter. Instead of a subclass, put a visual child in the Content of an instance of the control. The child can have its own template and its own content. Its Content could be a further child, ad (nearly) infinitum.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thank you, that solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the *ControlTemplate* to achive this

1.you could define a ControlTemplate at the application level,in `App.xmal`

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="SubContentPageTemplate">
             <StackLayout>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image x:Name="BackIcon" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                           Grid.Row="0" />
                    <Label x:Name="TitleLabel" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold"
                           TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="0" />
                </Grid>
                <ContentPresenter  />
            </StackLayout>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

2.use in your `FilterPage.xaml`

```
<ContentPage>
    <ContentView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource SubContentPageTemplate}">
     <StackLayout>
        <Label  x:Name="SearchLabel" Text="Search keyword" 
            TextColor="Black" FontSize="Large" Margin="10,10,0,0" />
        <Editor x:Name="SearchEditor" Placeholder="Type a keyword"
            PlaceholderColor="Gray" Margin="10,10,10,0"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
     </StackLayout>
   </ContentView>   
</ContentPage>
```

more infomation you could refet to [ControlTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/creating)